# Query most sold products, join 3 tables - Laravel 9

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to filter the most sold products and show them later in a view, (top 10 most sold).

I have 3 tables:

- products

  - id
  - name
- invoice_items

  - name
  - item_quantity
  - product_id
- saleorder_items

  - name
  - item_quantity
  - product_id

As you may guess, in `products` table, I have my list of products and when a purchase is made, it goes into `invoice_items` table or `saleorder_items` table according to the customer's invoice request.

I want to make a query where it searches products on `invoice_items` table and `saleorder_items` table and combine the `item_quantity` field, if they have the same `product_id` field.

So far I have done this:

```php
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('invoice_items', 'products.id', '=', 'invoice_items.product_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('products.name, sum(invoice_items.item_quantity) as invoice'))
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderBy('invoice', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

The code works and I get a list of top 10 `invoice_items` product, however when I want to join `saleorder_items` table because I want a combined top 10 list (there might be product with the same `id` so I can count that as a total), it goes wrong and shows only the products which are in both table only...

```php
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('invoice_items', 'products.id', '=', 'invoice_items.product_id')
    ->leftJoin('saleorder_items', 'products.id', '=', 'saleorder_items.product_id')
    ->selectRaw('products.*, COALESCE(sum(invoice_items.item_quantity + saleorder_items.item_quantity),0) sold')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderBy('sold','desc')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
```

I've already achieved the result of only 2 tables, `products` and `invoice_items` however I can't seem to get 3 tables to work for a combined results of top 10...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your requirements without the ORM, which is here:

```
SELECT products.*, total_sold.sold
FROM products
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, sum(item_quantity) as sold
    FROM (
        SELECT product_id, item_quantity
        FROM invoice_items
        UNION ALL
        SELECT product_id, item_quantity
        FROM saleorder_items
    ) AS sold_quantities
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS total_sold ON products.id = total_sold.product_id
ORDER BY sold DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And adapted it for Eloquent (untested):

```php
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join(
        DB::raw(
            '(
                SELECT product_id, sum(item_quantity) as sold
                FROM (
                    SELECT product_id, item_quantity
                    FROM invoice_items
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT product_id, item_quantity
                    FROM saleorder_items
                ) AS sold_quantities
                GROUP BY product_id
            ) AS total_sold'
        ),
        'products.id',
        '=',
        'total_sold.product_id'
    )
    ->selectRaw('products.*, total_sold.sold')
    ->orderBy('sold', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks it did work, however i can't accept your answer since i've < 15 reputation.